# Will this trigger always complete before returning results of Insert to client?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, azure-sql-database

I have the following trigger for Auditing.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TR_MyTrigger ON dbo.Cust
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @EntityState AS SMALLINT;
    SET @EntityState = (CASE
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) THEN 3 -- Updated
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 4 -- Inserted
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) THEN 2 -- Deleted
                    ELSE NULL END)
    IF @EntityState = 4
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Cust 
        SET Created = GETDATE(), Updated = GETDATE() 
        FROM INSERTED I
        WHERE Cust.BinId = I.BinId
    END
    ELSE IF @EntityState = 3
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Cust 
        SET Updated = GETDATE() 
        FROM INSERTED I
        WHERE Cust.BinId = I.BinId
    END
    IF @EntityState <> 2
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditEntries (SomeColumns..) 
        SELECT SomeColumns..
        FROM INSERTED I;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditEntries (SomeColumns..) 
        SELECT SomeColumns..
        FROM DELETED I;
    END
END;
```

When the client(API Server) call writing to the table `Cust` is complete, the next call inserts `userIds` to the `AuditEntries` table.

Extra info:

- There exist no other triggers anywhere.
- Client uses EntityFramework Core so time in question is after `SaveChangesAsync()` returns.
- The PrimaryKey of the `AuditEntries` table is the `ROWVERSION` of `dbo.Cust`

**The question is**: are the `AuditEntries` guaranteed to exist at this time or is this a race I need to handle?

Other research:

[sql-server-trigger-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631192/sql-server-trigger-execution)

[An answer to: Are Sql Triggers synchronous or asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210097/are-sql-triggers-synchronous-or-asynchronous#answer-210141)

**UPDATE**: The above trigger does not enter a loop via direct recursion on any update operations due to the default T-Sql configuratoin.  See: [Recursive Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#recursive-triggers)

Found an SO this am that answers my original question: [Does a trigger in a transaction only fire when the transaction is committed?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154810/does-a-trigger-in-a-transaction-only-fire-when-the-transaction-is-committed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELTE the UPDATE from your trigger

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TR_MyTrigger ON dbo.Cust
    AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
```

When you delete the UPDATE trigger Case 4 and 3 wouldn't fire the  trigger again.

So only when you INSERT or DELETE, the trigger would run, and update Cust or insert into AuditEntries

With this AFTER UPDATE TRiGGER you would create a loop.

so you should write another triigger only for UPDATES, if you need one.

To answer your question

The trigger would run after the INSER or DELETE of dbo.Cust and will  run completely before starting another command, that is because you define  your trigger  as FOR EACH STATEMENT

As Example

1. INSERT INTO dbo.Cust VALUE (1,),(2,),(3,),(4,),(5,)
2. TRIGGER dbo.TR_MyTrigger
3. INSERT INTO dbo.Cust VALUE (6,),(7,),(8,),(9,),(10,)
4. TRIGGER dbo.TR_MyTrigger
5. DELETE dbo.Cust ...
6. TRIGGER dbo.TR_MyTrigger#

Every step is completed before the next

Comment: Hmm,  I definitely need to handle that loop.  And thank you.  If I remove the offending portion of setting updated / created.  Can you speak to the original question?

Comment: The trigger would run after the INSER or DELETE of dbo.Cust and will  run completly before starting another command., that is because you define  your trigger  FOR EACH STATEMENT

Comment: @ngk, I spent some time looking particularly into the update loop and can't verify it exists. I updated Question with code I would expect to repro but doesn't seem to.  I am not clear on what you mean by "because you define your trigger FOR EACH STATEMENT" - But I need to know if inserting into `dbo.Cust` -> which causes trigger to run(at least once-hopefully no more) will complete its insertion record into `AuditEntries` table before the client's `dbo.Cust` inserting code invocation returns..  Your example doesn't explicitly answer this part that is the key question I have.  Thank you again

Comment: Previous comment was in response to [@nbk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/190821/nbk).  I misspelled and its too late to edit.

Comment: AFTER triggers are not triggerd by DML performed by the trigger itself, by default.  This is controlled by the RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS database option, which is off by default.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-nested-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15#recursive-triggers